# Unable to connect to Wireless after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, asus, atheros, intel-wireless

I am using Asus U56E laptop and after installing Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8, I am unable to connect to the Wireless. I have been trying to solve this problem since two weeks and couldn't solve it. Please help. Any answer would be appreciated.

Here are some command-line results.

lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network
    02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 (rev 67)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 BGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at de800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

lsmod | grep iwlwifi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi

iwlwifi               386826  0 

mac80211              539908  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              206566  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   57.846261] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   57.846264] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[   57.846336] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   57.846338] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >pci_resource_base = ffffc90000c7c000
[   57.846341] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >HW Revision ID = 0x67
[   57.846438] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >irq 52 for MSI/MSI-X
[   59.558335] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >loaded firmware version 41.28.5.1 build 33926
[   59.558514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   59.558516] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   59.558517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   59.558519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE enabled
[   59.558520] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P disabled
[   59.558522] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 BGN, REV=0x84
[   59.558583] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   59.569083] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >device EEPROM VER=0x557, CALIB=0x6
[   59.569085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Device SKU: 0x150
[   59.569087] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Valid Tx ant: 0x1, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[   59.569100] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[   70.208469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   70.208648] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   70.366319] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   70.366470] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: >Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c network
      *-network               
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           logical name: wlan0
           version: 67
           serial: 40:25:c2:84:99:c4
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-17-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
           resources: irq:52 memory:de800000-de801fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
           vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           logical name: eth0
           version: c0
           serial: 54:04:a6:2b:6a:ef
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:54 memory:dd400000-dd43ffff ioport:a000(size=128)
```

ifconfig

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:04:a6:2b:6a:ef  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:176 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:14368 (14.3 KB)  TX bytes:14368 (14.3 KB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:25:c2:84:99:c4  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

iwconfig

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

iwlist scan

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ iwlist scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results
```

nm-tool

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        54:04:A6:2B:6A:EF

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        40:25:C2:84:99:C4

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    hypeness2:       Infra, 00:21:29:DA:08:4F, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 42 WPA
    love:            Infra, 68:7F:74:17:02:66, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    DIRECT-MwSCX-3400Pamela: Infra, 02:15:99:A3:3F:AC, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA2
    router:          Infra, 1C:AF:F7:D6:76:F3, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA2
    wing:            Infra, E8:40:F2:34:E4:F7, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA WPA2
    132LINKSYS:      Infra, 00:1A:70:80:1F:E9, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WEP
    VMITTAL:         Infra, E0:46:9A:3C:F0:C4, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WEP
    HP-Print-10-LaserJet 1025: Infra, 7C:E9:D3:7E:F8:10, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59
    ACNBB:           Infra, 00:26:75:22:A6:2F, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20
    SATKAIVAL:       Infra, 00:18:E7:CE:69:A6, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA WPA2
    hypeness:        Infra, B8:E6:25:24:C3:B1, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    CSNetwork:       Infra, BC:14:01:58:C5:88, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA WPA2
    tharma:          Infra, BC:14:01:E2:06:18, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15 WPA WPA2
    Active2.4:       Infra, 10:6F:3F:0E:F3:8E, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA WPA2
    ACNBB:           Infra, 00:26:75:58:4E:7A, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 85
    KO:              Infra, BC:14:01:2E:AF:A8, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA WPA2
    FEAR:            Infra, 00:18:4D:C0:BC:58, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 17 WPA
    Pamela:          Infra, BC:14:01:52:F6:F8, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2
    bvrk2:           Infra, 78:CD:8E:7B:3C:79, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    BELL030:         Infra, D8:6C:E9:17:AF:09, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA2
    Desai:           Infra, 00:1D:7E:52:FB:C5, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 14 WEP
    Sritharan:       Infra, BC:14:01:E5:59:78, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2
    PFN:             Infra, 00:13:10:8B:CF:45, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WEP
```

rfkill list all

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wimax: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

so these are some more results

sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

echo "blacklist asus_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etcmodprobe.d/blacklist.conf

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "blacklist asus_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist asus_wmi
```

echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
rmmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
```

sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko 11n_disable=1
```

Comment: can you try the steps mentioned here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010968 see if those helps. If they do I will provide the answer here in a friendlier format. I do not have the same Wifi Card to test. So please, test it with the suggestions mentioned there and see if that helps.

Comment: that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This will keep power management enabled, but it will limit your wifi speed and range to 802.11g speeds.

1. Run the following commands

   ```
   sudo rmmod iwlwifi
   sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
   ```
2. Make sure that wireless connectivity is restored. To make this change permanent, create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d` and put the following in it:

   ```
   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
   ```
3. Reboot to see changes.